# How to recover a SD card?

Tags: files

I accidentally deleted my SD card photos.

I purchased a software call wondershare photo recovery and card recovery. I am able to recover back 50% of my photos.

But I got some strange issues here.

Actually I am able to recovered all photos.
But only old photo (mean 1 or 2 years back) are recovered in full size (3-5MB), the latest photos (all 2013) were recovered in 30-100KB only. From thumbnail and the mega tag, I am able to see the image and information. But when I open the image file. Its look like fragments.

Since the day I accidentally deleted the photos, I had never use this SD card anymore to avoid data overlap. But I really dont understand why I can recovered those old photos, the latest photos all is fragments?

Comment: Did your software purchase come with any user support?

Comment: Which file system does it have?

Comment: What did you actually do so far? More detail would be very useful.

Comment: Have you deleted some of the old pictures before and then added new ones? So some of the new pictures could become fragmented.

Comment: Please search the site before asking these types of basic questions. They've been covered extensively already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by fragmented you mean that the JPEG images (as that is the most commonly encoutered image format) are "pixelated" or have strange artefacts like stripes it means that the files haven't been recovered fully.

Now if the card itself is working, try cloning it with `dd` into a file:

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p1 of=/path/to/image bs=1M
```

and work on the resulting image - it will be faster and you won't have to worry about accidentally damaging the only copy of your data. When one is trying to rescue the data from a media damaged in any way (e.g. a dying HDD), [`ddrescue`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue#Data_recovery) is the right choice.

The file system usually used on SD cards is [FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) (which has actually a rather simple structure), so you probably want to look around for utilities that would try to reconstruct that (these utilities have been around since DOS times, one example can be the [Norton Utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Utilities#1.0)).

Comment: I suggest you use http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue instead of `dd`

Comment: If the card is working, there really is no need for this. In the case of a damaged media, `ddrescue` is the right choice of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `photorec` from the testdisk package, but all recovery attempts are just last ditch desperation measures that fail more often than not.  This is why you need to have backups of data you don't want to lose.

Comment: I did purchased the software call cardrescue and wondershare, but non of the works. My file is just .jpeg file only.
I had tried to recover the SD card, then in my recovery files. Only old photos (those 1-2 years ago photo able to recover), but recent photos like few months ago. I unable to recover it, as the file size only 35kb-100kb only. I think its just a thumbnails.

Comment: @user1343112, there's no need to repeat yourself.